# MySQL Grouping Rankings

Tags: mysql, search, grouping, ranking

I have the following query:

```
SELECT @rn:=@rn+1 AS rank, pet_name, pet_count
FROM (
  SELECT pet_name, COUNT(*) AS pet_count
  FROM pets
  WHERE pet_breed="cat"
  GROUP BY pet_name
  ORDER BY pet_count DESC
) t1, (SELECT @rn:=0) t2
```

which produces output like this:

```
1   Kitty   87
2   Smokey  81
3   Bella   80
4   Oreo    63
5   Charlie 63
6   Tiger   62
7   Lucy    62
8   Jack    61
9   Tigger  60
```

The problem is that Oreo and Charlie, Tiger and Lucy should be ranked the same since they are both 63 so that the results would look like

```
1   Kitty   87
2   Smokey  81
3   Bella   80
4   Oreo    63
4   Charlie 63
5   Tiger   62
5   Lucy    62
6   Jack    61
7   Tigger  60
```

I just can't figure out the tweak to get it the way I want.

Suggestions?

Comment: pls provide some sample data

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT IF((@previous = pet_count, @rn, @rn:=@rn+1) AS rank, pet_name, pet_count, @previous := pet_count
FROM (
  SELECT pet_name, COUNT(*)  AS pet_count
  FROM pets
  WHERE pet_breed="cat"
  GROUP BY pet_name
  ORDER BY pet_count DESC
) t1, (SELECT @rn:=0) t2
```

I did not try this in actual. But concept will work

Comment: Brilliant! This solved my slightly different issue as well with starting ranking at 1 again if a new group started.